# Rails: Error running rake due to different ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm, chatwoot

I'm using a self-hosted [chatwoot](https://chatwoot.com) installation on AWS using ubuntu.

I'm upgrading the chatwoot version following the [guide](https://www.chatwoot.com/docs/self-hosted/deployment/linux-vm) but when i want to precompile the assets, I run into an error

```
Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 3.0.2
```

But when i get the ruby version, it states that my version is already the same as specified in the Gemfile.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrLKs.png)

I'm kind of loss at this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also I am confused where does the ruby 2.7.0 comes from, as my rvm is already using ruby 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You better install Ruby 2.7.0 for compatibility. The Ruby version in your local machine is different from the one declared in Gemfile.

If you're using rvm:

```
rvm install 2.7.0
rvm use 2.7.0
```

else if you're using rbenv:

```
rbenv install 2.7.0
rbenv local 2.7.0
```

Comment: My gemfile needs ruby 3.0.2 why would I install ruby 2.7???